# Android - Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection,

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, apache

i got this error when i started my eclipse indigo and updated it, and i too updated SDK . After this i tried to run my Hello World Program i got the error :

```
[2013-12-13 10:54:49 - SimulationExample] ------------------------------
[2013-12-13 10:54:49 - SimulationExample] Android Launch!
[2013-12-13 10:54:49 - SimulationExample] Connection with adb was interrupted.
[2013-12-13 10:54:49 - SimulationExample] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
[2013-12-13 10:54:49 - SimulationExample] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

And After few seconds i got error this too.

```
[2013-12-13 10:40:02 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection
[2013-12-13 10:45:57 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2013-12-13 10:45:58 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

pls anybody help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many antiviruses stop some .exe file to run on the system this will be the cause of my problem, some of them stop loopback address to access., i have uninstalled it and recovered from errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of reasons for this type of cause.To solve this,

Case 1 :

1) In the perspective choose DDMS.

2) In the Devices tab, there is a row of icons.In the right of the icons there is a down arrow.

3)Click the down arrow and then click "Reset adb".

case 2:
You need to Check whether your JRE version is compitable with your SDK or not.

case 3:
Restart Your eclipse. If you have number of eclipse close others, that may be issue. Same issues can be happened with Number of Emulators too.

Comment: hey i did all those steps and also i have installed updated JDK, I am unable to recover.

Comment: Hai Thnk you for reply. i got it. i uninstalled anti virus and thnks it work for me.